# How to replace container by components?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have sidebar component that have to show different compnents depends event data.

Now anywhere in application I send command using `Subject()` with data:

```
{data: {}, type: "showSearch"} 
{data: {}, type: "showResultSearch"}
{data: {}, type: "showUserBlock"} 
{data: {}, type: "showContacts"}
```

Then in `SideBarComponent` I listen this data and apply to varaible type:

```
this.events.listen().subject((data) => {
     this.type = data.type;
);
```

Then inside template `SideBarComponent` I do:

```
<app-search *ngIf="type === 'showSearch'"></app-search>
<app-result-search *ngIf="type === 'showResultSearch'"></app-result-search>
<app-user-block *ngIf="type === 'showUserBlock'"></app-user-block>
<app-contracts *ngIf="type === 'showContacts'"></app-contacts>
```

So, how to solve this more graceful? Now I have more then 10 components.

Comment: You can have look at `*ngSwitch` directive.

Comment: This is a use case for the router. Not any ngIf or ngSwitch or dynamic components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `*ngIf` or even an `ngSwitch` block, you could use an *object* and render components dynamically, like this:

**Angular < 9**:

*Module*:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts.component.ts';
import { ResultSearchComponent } from './result-search.component.ts';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component.ts';
import { UserBlockComponent } from './user-block.component.ts';

const ENTRY_COMPONENTS = [
  ContactsComponent,
  ResultSearchComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  UserBlockComponent,
];
const DECLARATIONS = [
  ...ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
  AppComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: DECLARATIONS,
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  entryComponents: ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*Component*:

```
import { Component, Type } from '@angular/core';

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts.component';
import { ResultSearchComponent } from './result-search.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import { UserBlockComponent } from './user-block.component';

const componentsMapper = {
  showContacts: ContactsComponent,
  showResultSearch: ResultSearchComponent,
  showSearch: SearchComponent,
  showUserBlock: UserBlockComponent,
  // others
};
```

---

**Angular 9**:

*Module*:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*Component*:

```
import { Component, Type } from '@angular/core';

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const componentsMapper = {
  showContacts: import('./contacts.component').then(({ ContactsComponent }) => ContactsComponent),
  showResultSearch: import('./result-search.component').then(({ ResultSearchComponent }) => ResultSearchComponent),
  showSearch: import('./search.component').then(({ SearchComponent }) => SearchComponent),
  showUserBlock: import('./user-block.component').then(({ UserBlockComponent }) => UserBlockComponent),
  // others
};
```

---

Common code for any **Angular** version (9 to down):

*Template*:

```
<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="ngComponentOutlet$ | async"></ng-template>
```

*Component*:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly ngComponentOutlet$ = this.events.listen().pipe(
    switchMap(data => this.loadComponent(data.type))
  );

  async loadComponent(type: string): Promise<Type<any>> {
    return await componentsMapper[type];
  }
}
```

---

As you may have noticed, the difference between two version is just that, in Angular 9, it isn't necessary to add dynamic components to the *entryComponents* section in `@NgModule` and not even in the *declarations*. The code can be imported really dynamically, on demand.

---

[**Angular < 9 DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxcptd)
[**Angular 9 DEMO**](https://ng-run.com/edit/G5mA76eE55AHwUEFmJ3a)

Read more:

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/asynchronous-modules-and-components-in-angular-ivy-1c1d79d45bd3

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8

https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a

Comment: Why not just use the router

Comment: @bryan60 hmm, I'm not sure each component described by OP is actually represented by router. When I read the question I didn't have this perspective, but now you mention it, I'm in doubt as to what the real intention is.. haha :)

Comment: Any component can be routed. Just stick a router outlet in there and write the router config

Comment: @bryan60 Huh? Of course any component can be routed. At no time did I say otherwise, not least because it would be stupid. I guess you didn't understand what I answered you. Let's try again: I said that I'm not sure that those components are actually represented by routes (ex. `/contacts` -> `app-contacts`, `/user/:id` -> `user-block`). For me, it's a single page showing a component based on a condition, or at least was what I understood when I read the question. If it's a router problem or something else, the question needs to be clarified by @Muhhamed.

Comment: It’s not currently represented by the router. Im suggesting why not jus use the router to represent it rather than deal with all this.

Comment: @Muhhamed I posted a solution for Angular < 9 and Angular 9.

Answer (score -1):

I think I would recommend you to use router and its features, I would say these components seems like they should be displayed by the url of your app.

url would represent which resource you're accessing for egz:

```
my-app/search

my-app/contacts
```

https://angular.io/guide/router